# Not able to call a function such as setState in Creatableselect of the select Component

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I need to use the CreatableSelect in my form especially for the fact that I can use it to create new elements and add to my list. I have gone through the documentation as stated here https://react-select.com/creatable but I am not able to get the list of objects and set to a State value as it gives me the error this.setState is not a function

I have tried writing another function, passing it as an element to the metaAction property of the function and using it within to pass the newValue to the function and use setState there but I still get function not defined. But the console.log(newValue) display so well.

```
handleTagsChange(newValue: any, actionMeta:any ){
   console.group('Value Changed');
    console.log(newValue);
    const { info } = this.state;
    this.setState({
        info: {
            ...info,
            feats: newValue
        }
    });
    console.log(`action: ${actionMeta.action}`);
    console.groupEnd();
}
```

I am expecting to set my feats with newValues instead, I get error that this.state is  not a function. Please any ideas around this will be greatly appreciated

Comment: I think `handleTagsChange` function is not bound to react component...Please add more code so that we can help

Comment: oops, can't imagine how little things can mess someone up. thanks for this comment

Answer (score 0):

@AviatorX should be correct. Try to turn your code into arrow function

```
handleTagsChange = (newValue: any, actionMeta:any ) => {
...
}
```